# Intercepting object creation in RavenDb

Tags: aop, json.net, ravendb

I am trying to run some code on objects that are loaded from RavenDB, and I need to do it just after the object has been loaded with its property values.

I've tried intercepting the deserialization process using a CustomCreationConverter and overriding ReadJson, but the object I can access at that point has all the properties set, except the one I need : the Id. Is there somewhere else I can slot into the pipeline in order to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you don't see the Id is because it's not part of the document, it's in the metadata as `@id`.

If you want to intercept client side, you can register a custom *Conversion Listener*.  Create a class that implements `IDocumentConversionListener` and register it with `documentStore.RegisterListener()`.  In the `DocumentToEntity` method, you can run your custom logic.  The documentation is lacking on Listeners in general, but there is another topic that also uses them:
http://ravendb.net/kb/16/using-optimistic-concurrency-in-real-world-scenarios

The other option would be to add a bundle that intercepts on the server side.  For that, you would use a [Read Trigger](http://ravendb.net/docs/server/extending/triggers/read).